# Linq Inner join for different column in same table

Tags: performance, linq

I have below linq query.

```
    (from q in table1 
join u1 in table2 on q.Field1 = u1.Id
join u2 in table2 on q.Field2 = u2.Id
join u3 in table2 on q.Field3 = u3.Id
select q.Id, u1.Name, u2.Name, u3.Name)
```

You can see, There are three times join on table2 with different column on table1.

Is there any way to achieve above result with single join on table2?

Thanks
Imrankhan

Comment: What is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have given example query. 
let assume, I have two table named Comment and User. In comment table, I have User table reference like, AssignedTo, CreatedBy, UserId. Now I want a query that return name of AssignTo, CreatedBy and UserId along with Comment Text with single join query,

Comment: @Imrankhan, did my answer help you to solve the issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the additional `join`s with anonymous objects:

```
var query = from q in table1 
            join u1 in table2 
            on new { q.Field1, q.Field2, q.Field3 } equals 
               new { u1.Id, u1.Id, u1.Id }
            select new {q.Id, u1.Name};
```

or with `where`s:

```
var query = from q in table1 
            join u1 in table2 on q.Field1 equals u1.Id
            where q.Field2 == u1.Id &&
                  q.Field3 == u1.Id
            select new {q.Id, u1.Name};
```